# How to create a virtual switch with Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v

I have a very simple scenario. I have a Windows Server 2012 box and I've just installed Hyper-V on the server.

After the installation I want to create a Virtual Switch to be able to get access to my network and to the internet from my VMs.

I'm creating an external switch, and configuring the virtual network adapter with the same IPV4 configuration than the original configuration of my physical network adapter without any success.

The network connection of my physical server is broken and I don't manage to fix it without removing the virtual switch.

Can you tell me how to do this ?

Regards,

Comment: I have an additionnal hint, the default gateway is lost every time I want to save it.

Comment: Something isn't right. IPv6 shouldn't need to be disabled. If it resolved the problem then it's a fluke. This isn't the correct resolution for the problem. Are you allowing the Management OS to share the virtual switch? Can you post a screenshot of the virtual switch settings in Hyper-V Manager and the settings of the network adapters on the Hyper-V host? If you're sharing the virtual switch with the Management OS then include a screenshot of the settings of the virtual Ethernet adapter that is created for the virtual switch.

Answer (score -3):

After half a day of research I have finally found that I had to disable IPV6 on the server to make everything works as expected...